# Android studio SDK stuck while downloading SDK components

Tags: android-studio

**After** installing Java and setting environment variables, I installed Android studio for the first time but it gets stuck while downloading SDK components.

I un-installed it and installed again, but it gets stuck again. I waited a lot but there is not any progress in downloading. I then cancelled the download and open the android studio, it again asks to download SDK components.

Will anyone help how to fix it and download SDK components ?

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete all the SDK files in the path c:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Then, try installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

I did nothing and just waited for an entire morning. It finally completed without any other issues, maybe it is a network speed issue, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, however after reading the replies to this. I tried again today. I didn't change anything, not deleted any files. I just launched the software and the download started progressing and finished in like 5 minutes. Weird but thankfully it was successful.
[image]